# asp.net jquery bootstrap datepicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Can somebody help me with this?
I've tried the with the input and it works alright but i want to use asp.net 
TEXTBOX with runat=server.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txttStart"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txttEnd"></asp:TextBox>
<input type="text" id="dpd1" placeholder="Begin Date" class="form-control input-sm" required /><br />
<input type="text" id="dpd2" placeholder="End Date" class="form-control input-sm" required />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var nowTemp = new Date();
    var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

    var checkin = $('#dpd1').datepicker({
        onRender: function(date) {
            return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
        }
    }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
        if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
            var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
            newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
            checkout.setValue(newDate);
        }
        checkin.hide();
        $('#dpd2')[0].focus();
    }).data('datepicker');
    var checkout = $('#dpd2').datepicker({
        onRender: function(date) {
            return date.valueOf() <= checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
        }
    }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
        checkout.hide();
    }).data('datepicker');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#datetimepicker').datepicker();
    })
</script>

<input id="datetimepicker" type="text">
```

i think this code help you.

Comment: thank you for your help but what i meant was that <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="datetitmepicker" /> instead of <input id="datetimepicker" type="text"> becaust when i use the <input /> it works fine but when i use asp.net textbox, it doesn't work so my question is how can i get the textbox working?

Comment: @Gabriel Takyie  it is also use in aspx page.

Comment: if you have any query please comment.

Comment: I know it is used in aspx page but i rather prefer using the textbox than < <input />

Comment: <asp:textbox id="datetimepicker" runat="server">

Comment: aspx page is content page or normal aspx page

Answer (score 0):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#datetimepicker').datepicker();
    })
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">


<%--<input id="datetimepicker" type="text">--%>
<asp:TextBox ID="datetimepicker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my running code.use it.